# Automate chapter replication

Tags: vba, ms-word

Me and my colleague are looking to automate a protocol creation that is quite standard. There are some tests that should be repeated for example 3 times and we would like to replicate that chapter increasing the test number.

let's explain

I have this heading and it's content

1.1 [Variable].TEST.001: Verification of Pippo
Some test description 
1.2 [Variable].TEST.001: Post-Run Conclusion

We would like a User form that ask how many time you need to perform the test? Insert 3 for example and the system will create automatically

1.3 [Variable].TEST.002: Verification of Pippo
Some test description 
1.4 [Variable].TEST.002: Post-Run Conclusion

1.5 [Variable].TEST.003: Verification of Pippo
Some test description 
1.6 [Variable].TEST.003: Post-Run Conclusion

Something like that we tried to search something but probably we used the wrong keywords or something like that....

Hope you can help us...

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. If you create the first and last lines of each block using an outline numbered style, then you can store the block in AutoText. Then your VBA only has to insert the AutoText 3 times and update the number after TEST.00.

Comment: I haven't written code because I have no idea where to start... I'm trying to understand how to start... if you could help me with something that I can read and try it will be really helpful.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a code-writing service. Here are some helpful links for learning VBA in PowerPoint: https://www.brightcarbon.com/blog/how-to-use-vba-in-powerpoint/ http://www.pptfaq.com/#name_PROGRAMMING_POWERPOINT http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/powerpoint_hints_and_tips_tutorials.html#vba http://skp.mvps.org/vba.htm#.XiHixchKhuc